# multiple same categorical variables into one hot encoded columns efficiently

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

How do I encode the table below efficiently?

e.g.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [1, 3, 4]]), columns=['col_1', 'col_2', 'col_3'])

   col_1  col_2  col_3
0      1      2      3
1      2      3      4
2      1      3      4
```

to

```
       1      2      3      4
0      1      1      1      0
1      0      1      1      1
2      1      0      1      1
```

Comment: @KhalilAlHooti which part is different? I would like to convert the df from the first box to the second box

Comment: Did the posted solution work for you?

Comment: @Divakar yeah, it's roughly the same as how i did it. Was wondering if there is any one-liner python codes for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way -

```
def hotencode(df):
    unq, idx = np.unique(df, return_inverse=1)
    col_idx = idx.reshape(df.shape)
    out = np.zeros((len(col_idx),col_idx.max()+1),dtype=int)
    out[np.arange(len(col_idx))[:,None], col_idx] = 1
    return pd.DataFrame(out, columns=unq, index=df.index)
```

Another way with `broadcasting` would be -

```
unq = np.unique(df)
out = (df.values[...,None] == unq).any(1).astype(int)
```

Sample run -

```
In [81]: df
Out[81]: 
   col_1  col_2  col_3
0      1      2      3
1      2      3      4
2      1      3      4

In [82]: hotencode(df)
Out[82]: 
   1  2  3  4
0  1  1  1  0
1  0  1  1  1
2  1  0  1  1
```

Comment: this is an excellent method, I am using it for a similar problem. How would this function be edited in order to return sum of instances instead of 0/1? So for example if for index 0 the values were 1, 2, 2 instead of 1, 2, 3, would it be possible for the output of `hotencode` to have as its first row (index 0) 1, 2, 0, 0 instead of 1, 1, 1, 0?